# Swagger responseContainer = "List" not working

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, resteasy, swagger, swagger-ui

Below is my interface

```
@Api(value = "/abc/def", basePath = "/abc/def", description = "")
public interface test{

   @ApiOperation(value = "some description" , response = SomeDTO.class ,responseContainer = "List" )
   @ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful response"),          
   })

   @GET
   @Path("/{Id}")
   List<SomeDTO> getById(@PathParam("Id") String Id);
}
```

In the Swagger UI when i provide the Id and Click on Try out it doesn't display the list of results . It just hangs.

Below are my Dependencies

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
         <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.10</version>
      </dependency>
```

SomeDTO Looks like below in Swagger UI

```
SomeDTO {
Id (integer, optional),
TestType (TestType, optional) = ['QA' or 'PROD'],  // enum in java class
Time (string, optional),
Status (Status, optional) = ['Y' or 'N'],  // enum in java class
}
```

SomeDTO.java

```
public class SomeDTO {
    private Integer Id;
    private TestType testType;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date Time;    
    private Status status;    

// getters and setters  

}
```

I am able to get the results by Chrome Poster Plugin .

Can someone please let me know what i have missed while configuring swagger to return a list of SomeDTO types..

Comment: swagger-annotations alone will not produce anything. Please check and share which top-level library you use and what's its version. Most likely one of swagger-jaxrs, swagger-jersey-jaxrs, swagger-jersey2-jaxrs. Also, it would help to see the actual Swagger definition output you get for the getById operation.

Comment: to add to @Ron comment - here are some samples you can start with https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/master/samples

Comment: to add to @Zavael - swagger now has a dedicated repo for samples https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/